# Are Chao like Cheese related to Chaos (the monster or the emeralds)

Tags: sonic-the-hedgehog

I wanna know if Chao, such as Cream's friend, Cheese, are of any significance to the lore of Chaos the monster in the anime *Sonic X*, or even the Chaos Emeralds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chaos](https://chao-island.com/wiki/Chaos) is indeed a mutated Chao. His Perfect Chaos form is the result of absorbing the seven Chaos Emeralds.

> A mutated Chao. Possessing high intelligence and abilities that far exceed those of the rest. A gentle personality; once profiting from the power of the seven Chaos Emeralds, which guaranteed clear water around the altar and protected its race from foreign tribes. However, Knuckles' ancestors were a war-like people and slaughtered many of [Chaos'] fellow Chao in order to plunder the Chaos Emeralds, causing the enraged Chaos to go berserk, absorbing the 7 Chaos Emeralds and transforming into Perfect Chaos. The resultant heavy floods destroyed the civilisation.